# Help with formatting a thesis

Tags: table-of-contents

I am having a lot of trouble with trying to format my document properly. I feel like I have started to use way too many packages. But I am happy with the formatting overall the biggest issue I am having is that my table of contents page is not displaying the chapters above the sections that belong to each chapter.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, left=1.25in, bottom=1.75in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centerline{Table of contents}}}

\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}
\newcommand\Chapter[2]{\chapter
    [#1\hfil\hbox{}\protect\linebreak{\itshape#2}]%
    {#1\\[2ex]\Large\itshape#2}%
}
\newlength{\bracewidth}

\newcommand{\myunderbrace}[2]{\settowidth{\bracewidth}{$#1$}#1\hspace*{-1\bracewidth}\smash{\underbrace{\makebox{\phantom{$#1$}}}_{#2}}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{comment}

%\begin{comment}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep} % dots after chapter entries
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{8em} % increase space for chapter numbers
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER } % put this before chapter numbers

 


\begin{document}
        
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{2}    
    \input{Dedication}
    
    \input{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \listoffigures
    
    \listoftables
    
    \input{Chapter_1}
    
    \input{Chapter_2}
        
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    %\input{Chapters}
    
    \input{Appendix}
    
\end{document}
```

Here is what the current output looks like
[image]

If you have any recommendations to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.
I am also working on condensing all of the packages to simplify at well

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would say that loading 14 packages is definitely not "way too many". However, we cannot really test your code, since it loads external files, which we don't know. If I comment out all the `\input` macros, place `\chapter{Example chapter}` in your code instead and compile it, the chapter titles do show up in the ToC.  So, make sure that you got a `\chapter{...}` macro in each of your external files for the chapters.

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use the usual sections for```\documentclass{report}```? The table of contents shouldn't be much of an issue if you divide the thesis with ```\chapter``` and then go down the levels ```\section```, ```subsection```, etc. You would only have to add ```maketitle``` after beginning the document. I don't know if I missed something or don't understand what you are doing, I'm sorry if that is the case. I used Overleaf's guides on thesis writing with LaTeX and it helped a lot.

Comment: I am using the normal sectioning, they are just embedded within each of the chapters in order to keep my main text file and clean as possible. I was having difficulty with my title page, where I couldn't get the formatting I wanted so I created a separate text file and that is while I am just inputting it.